# Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't install on my laptop with Win-7

Tags: installation, 12.04, laptop, cd

I have a hp Probook 4410s with Windows 7 as default OS. For the last two years I have Ubuntu side by side and the latest version was 11.10. I wanted to upgrade to 12.04 by installing wubi, which didn't work (in fact, only thing happened was removal of previous version of Ubuntu). Later I downloaded an iso file and burnt it onto a CD. The laptop didn't start while booting with installation CD. The screen turned blank after some time and that's all while I was able to install 12.04 on my desktop (Win XP, SP-3) with the same CD.

Comment: Why not try making a bootable USB? Also do verify that the iso you downloaded is not corrupt. Refer this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

Comment: Using **wubi** was not the correct step, to upgrade Ubuntu.  It would have prompted you to 'overwrite/replace' the existing Ubuntu install.  Do you know what steps were taken which removed your current install?

Answer (score 0):

> Why not try making a bootable USB? Also do verify that the iso you downloaded is not corrupt.

How should the iso be corrupt when it installs Ubuntu 12.04 on a desktop??